# how to use MySQL like for searching exact a value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a string that stored my table 'tbl_route' column  named 'route_nos'.

The string looks like **3,4,7,8,9,10,11,14,16,20**

i am searching two number from this whole string using MySQL LIKE operator.

```
$nosPos="1"; 
$qr=mysql_query("select * from tbl_route where routes_nos like '% $nosPos %'");
```

But when the query executes it returns rows. But there is no **1** present in this string. I found that LIKE takes the partial match of the no that present in 11 or 14 or 16. But i need the exact search..
How is it possible?

Comment: You could search for $nosPos = "1,"; Then remove the comma if you return a result. As long as the number is always immediately followed by a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$qr=mysql_query("select * from tbl_route where FIND_IN_SET($nosPos, routes_nos) ");
```

Refer [**Doc here**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Answer (score 0):

For exact match, do not include the string within %..%, but use it directly:

```
$qr=mysql_query("select * from tbl_route where routes_nos like '$nosPos'");
```